# How do I split intersecting squares?

Tags: python, opencv

The crux of the problem: you need to count the number of squares.
There is a picture on which there are noises, I removed them, but I do not know how to divide intersecting squares, or you can count squares without division.
I would be grateful for any help.

here is a picture with noises
https://i.stack.imgur.com/GmmzM.jpg

here is a picture without noise
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cF7i8.png)

code

```
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 


image = cv2.imread("1.bmp")
image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

_, binary = cv2.threshold(gray, 3, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
plt.imshow(binary, cmap="gray")
plt.show()
```

Comment: convolve with a kernel that represents the square. find peaks in the response. isolated squares will have best response, overlapping ones will have reduced response (but still clearly detectable). if they overlap too much, you won't be able to detect them. no way around it.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz please tell me how it will be, otherwise I don't quite understand